# AVAudioEngine optimize graph for multiple channel manipulation

Tags: core-audio, avaudioengine

I have a stereo signal and want to seperate it to modify either the left or right channel (e.g. eq only on the left)
Currently I'm setting up my graph as follows:

```
playernode1->mixer(pan=1) \
                           mainMixerNode
playernode2->mixer(pan=-1)/
```

playernode1 and playernode2 use the same file for playback

this seems to playback correctly and I can easily add an EQ after one of the channel mixer.

Another option I've found is as follows:

```
                     ConnectionNode(leftMixer(pan=-1)) - EQ
                    /                                       \
playerNode -> Mixer                                           mainMixerNode
                    \                                       /
                     ConnectionNode(rightMixer(pan=1)) - EQ
```

Which looks a lot more reasonable

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.